# TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <type 'NoneType'>

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient, floor

I encounter an error, code as below. I want to check the gradient of function floor, the error occurs:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def floor(x):
    return tf.floor(x)

# code
w1 = tf.Variable([[1.5, 0.5, -0.5, -1.5]])
res = floor(w1)

grads = tf.gradients(res, [w1])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    print(sess.run(grads))
```

[error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBElo.png)

Answer (score 1):

The gradient of the `floor()` function in TensorFlow is defined to return `None`, since the gradient of ⌊x⌋ is 0 everywhere (except at integers) and so this allows the backend code to treat it as having no connection.

See [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/897) for a relevant git issue.